# How to create an instance created from class-based views

Tags: django

I am learning Django's class-based views.
I don't understand what's the instance created from class Views

For example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

# views.py
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', MyView.as_view()),
]
```

What's the instance of class 'MyView' during this request-and-respond process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not very clear, I think that I get what you are asking:

Take a look at the source code of [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/conf/urls/#url) method:

> ```
> def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None):
>       if isinstance(view, (list, tuple)):
>           # For include(...) processing.
>           urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
>           return RegexURLResolver(
>               regex, urlconf_module, kwargs, 
>               app_name=app_name, namespace=namespace
>           )
>       ...
> ```

And a look at the [`as_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) method documentation:

> Returns a callable view that takes a request and returns a response:
>
> ```
> response = MyView.as_view()(request)
> ```
>
> The returned view has view_class and view_initkwargs attributes.
>     When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the HttpRequest is assigned to the view’s request attribute.

Therefore because you are passing in the `url` method the `MyView.as_view()` argument you are giving the instruction to **instantiate** the `MyView` class when a request object gets passed to the `url()` method.

Comment: I get it, receive a request instance and return an instance.